# Wordpress script localization in_category

Tags: wordpress

I have localized a script in my functions.php as follows:

```
wp_enqueue_script('script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', 'jquery', false);
$scriptParams = array( 'catWork' => in_category('9'), 'catNews' => in_category('10'), 'test' => 'localized'  );
wp_localize_script('script', 'scriptLocalize', $scriptParams);
```

I am then querying 2 separate categories and outputting thumbnails in 2 separate sections on the same page. I am loading in content via ajax when I click a thumbnail, but I need to detect what category the post is in with my javascript. Example:

```
$('.thumbnail').click(function() {
    if (scriptLocalize.catWork) {
      // Do something
    } else if (scriptLocalize.catNews) {
      // Do something else
    }
}
```

However, it does not seem to work. I am running the same thing on my search results page, which is running a general post loop, and it works fine. Is it not working because I am querying a particular category in this case? I know the script is localized, because if i run an alert on the 'test' variable it alerts 'localized' as it's supposed to.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is not working? Also can you confirm the post is in any of the categories and that `in_category()` returns true as it should?

Comment: It doesn't recognise whether the post it is loading is in a particular category or not, therefore the javascript function comes to a standstill. The posts are definitely in the specified categories. It works fine on my search results page though, which has led me to believe that it may be because I am querying a category. I also tried is_category(), but also did not work

Comment: If you do `var_dump( in_category(9) );` and `var_dump( in_category(10) );` before you localize the script, what is the result? `is_category()` checks if the current query is for a category page.

Comment: Do you mean pass var_dump( in_category(9) ); and var_dump( in_category(10) ) as an array?

Comment: I'm not following.. I mean just do the two calls on a post you know is associated with your work or news category. This should let us know if there's anything wrong with the PHP code.